# How to stop Orca from running when I open sound preferences?

Tags: configuration, accessibility, orca

I have this bizarre problem. whenever I  open sound preferences from indicator-sound in natty the orca speech-dispatcher runs in a terminal in a loop mode. I cannot close the terminal neither can I kill the process. I don't know what gnome-orca does except for it being a visual assistant application. Has anyone else faced this problem ??

[image]

Comment: What did you do in order to try to kill the process?

Comment: `sudo kill -9 orca-pid` .. I disabled visual assistant from startup application and its gone but I don't think thats the solution

Comment: I just had this issue (for weeks) with my Guake terminal locking up and finally figured out it was `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/orca`. It was mapped to a shortcut, `<alt> + <super> + s` that I accidentally pressed and I never turned it off. I simply pressed the shortcut again to turn it off then deleted the shortcut. I think this is the least heavy approach for my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **System Settings** then **Assistive Technologies**, and turn either turn it off completely, or change out orca in the Applications settings.

It may also work to just remove orca with  `sudo apt-get remove gnome-orca` .  This assumes you don't need Orca.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this wondering about this problem, and I solved it a different way at about the same time. This seems to happen if you disable Visual Assistance in Startup Preferences. I turned it back on and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. 11.04 beta. Tried `apt-get remove gnome-mag` with no luck. The simple hackish answer is

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/orca ~/orca
```

which will stop the program from opening, leaving the executable in your home directory, should you need to `mv` it back.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me, the way I got around it was to uninstall **gnome-orca** from the **Synaptic Package Manager** as I saw no reason for myself to have it.  After I'd uninstalled it, I didn't encounter anymore problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

Faced this issue. Sound was coming, even after removing orca.

Resolved by:

Go to sound settings. Click on Applications tab and switch-off speech dispatcher.

I hope it will help.